# Why is my editor not being pre-populated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In one of my programs, I have set up an "Edit" view/action method which is meant to allow me to edit the information of a particular table entry. The editor option works, but does not populate the editor with the current information. This results in the "Edit" option looking identical to my "Create" option, which is meant to allow the user to create a new entry.

Is there something I'm missing? The code for the view seemed to be almost identical to a tutorial I was following, yet they showed the result to be what you'd expect from an "Edit" option; an editor pre-populated with the entry's current information.

Below is the code for my view and action method. Thanks in advance.

View:

```
@model PharmTrack.Models.Doctor

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Doctor</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NPI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NPI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NPI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DEA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DEA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DEA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Index", "Index")
</div>
```

Action Method:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is most likely in the Controller. Please show us the Controller action for this.

Comment: @NineBerry I've added it in. I assumed it was negligible since it just returns the view. Of course if something is missing from the method, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the data of the object you want to edit into an instance of the model class and supply that to the View.

Code like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     PharmTrack.Models.Doctor doctor = LoadDoctorFromDatabase(id);
     return View(doctor);
}
```

Comment: I had actually just written something similar to that, and it worked. But I like your solution more; thanks for the help!

Comment: @AustinC This is the default Asp.net MVC way of doing this. It is not advised to load the data of the model from within the view or anything similar.